# Postgresql parametrized queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, parameters

I've recently heard that parametrized queries run faster on postgresql.

In an effort to test this, I decided to construct a parametrized ...

*OH I can already feel the down votes. wish I knew how to ask this better... please advise before voting down :)*

Does anyone know how to create a parametrized query?  I can't seem to find any docs on a raw sql string that is in fact a parametrized query.  I found a heap of VB || Java || php.. but these sadly don't IMHO equal sql.

To construct a parametrized query... do I have to create a function in the DB?

A nuts simple example of a query that makes use of parameters would be awesome.

The closest thing I can do to a code example would be. It doesn't come close to working.

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID = ? (1)
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please paste that link in an answer, so I can give you credit and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterized queries are typically a function of the client framework.  Different client frameworks have different semantics so your best option is to start with the client framework documentation.  This being said, low-level details help so I will go over the libpq interface here.  Many client frameworks wrap libpq's interface, so start with the [PQExecParams documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-MAIN).

In that function, your query is transformed using placeholders indicating the parameters used.  I believe these are actually sent to the db separately than the parameters which are then factored in during planning time (the planner of course is aware of the values of the arguments).

The placeholders follow a semantic structure of $1, $2, $3, etc. and so are identified by number.  Other frameworks wrap this using other placeholder syntax.